# ItemsSource binding and not working PropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I set `DataContext`:

```
this.DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
```

And I am binding the `ItemsSource` of a `TabControl`, when I add a new `TabItem` in the contructor of `MainWindowViewModel` it is working! But when I add a new `TabItem` in an event (Click) there is no effect.

I have this property:

```
List<Item> _listOfItem;
public List<Item> ListOfItem
{
    get
    {
        return _listOfItem;

    }
    set
    {
        _listOfItem = value;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ListOfItem"));
    }
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an `ObservableCollection`, rather than a `List` if you wish the UI to be notified of collection changes.

```
ObservableCollection<Item> _listOfItem;
public ObservableCollection<Item> ListOfItem
{
    get
    {
        return _listOfItem;
    }
    set
    {
        _listOfItem = value;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("ListOfItem"));
    }
}
```

Note that you only need to invoke the `PropertyChanged` event for your `ListOfItem` if the reference changes after construction of your view model type. If it doesn't change, then a simple auto property will suffice for `ListOfItem`.

Comment: It is to my understanding that you don't need to raise PropertyChanged on a ObservableCollection. So you can get rid of the property and only leave "Public ObservableCollection<Item> _listOfItem;". Mind you, this will only work for insert and delete (update = delete followed by insert).

Comment: No, you will need to invoke the PropertyChanged event if the reference to your observable collection changes in order to notify any UI elements. It's no different to any other property type in that regard.

Comment: I don't have a single view in all of my sourcecode where the reference of an observablecollection changes while the view is active. I only add INotifyPropertyChanged to the class stored in the OC to support updates. So I understand why you do this, but most of the times you wouldn't need the property.

Answer (score 1):

For collection changes you need the source collection to implement [`INotifyCollectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx), you could use an [`ObservableCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) (which implements it) instead of a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use and ObservableCollection for the UI to see additions and deletions to the collection.   It worked in the constructor as the List is was built for the the UI.

Answer (score 1):

List will not work.

You should use [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) for the ListOfItem.